# How to sort an array of objects by total score

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have an array of parent objects. Each parent has been given points and each parent has N children, each children has points as well. How can I sort the parents by total points descending (most points to least points). I've provided an example:

```
const parentsArray = [
{id:1, name: "Wendy", points:3, children: [{name: "Josh", points:2}, {name: "Josh", points: 15}]},
{id:2, name: "George", points: 10, children: [{name: "Mary", points:6}]},
{id:3, name: "Anne", points: 2, children: [{name: "Sarah", points:1.41},
{name: "Kim", points:0.41}]}
];
```

This is currently my code, but it only sorts on how to sort the points of the parent and does not take into account the points of the children:

```
parentsArray.sort((p1, p2) => (p2.points - p1.points));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value)

Comment: _"I've provided an example"_ - But not what you've tried so far...

Comment: lookup `array.sort`

Comment: I'm sorry, something must've gone wrong during publishing the question, I've added my code during my last edit @Andreas

Comment: Before you answer, make sure you couldn't find your answer in google.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [`Array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

```js
const parentsArray = [
{id:1, name: "Wendy", points:3, children: [{name: "Josh", points:2}, {name: "Josh"}]},
{id:2, name: "George", points: 10, children: [{name: "Mary", points:6}]},
{id:3, name: "Anne", points: 2, children: [{name: "Sarah", points:1.41},
{name: "Kim", points:0.41}]}
];
parentsArray.sort((a, b)=>{
  return b.points - a.points;
})
parentsArray.forEach((e)=>{
  e.children.sort((a,b)=>{return b.points - a.points});
})
console.log(parentsArray);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this only sorts on the points of the parents and not parents AND the children

Comment: @TeetoGo I've updated my answer. It should work now.